# Angular show/hide component on button click via dynamic variable

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have an HTML table that contains user records along with a button to edit the data. When they click on edit, I want to expose a component for them to make the changes in.

There is no specific amount of records and the data is never the same.

I am trying to wrap this new component in a dynamic `ngIf` statement and then toggle it with a dynamic button.

```
<tbody *ngFor="let r of mapRulesData.data | isArray: data; let i = index">

...

<span *ngIf="showRule_r.RuleParentID">
  <app-inline-select [selected]="a" [source]="fetchSourceList(a.AttributeID)" [ruleParentID]="r.RuleParentID" [attributeID]="a.AttributeID"></app-inline-select>
</span>

...

<li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="showRule_r.RuleParentID = !showRule_r.RuleParentID"><i class="fa fa-pencil padRight"></i>Edit Attribute</a></li>

</tbody>
```

I assume this would be something similar to `showRule_1234` where I can reference the single component that I want to display, even though there could be 50 other components on the page wrapped in the `ngIf` that are not visible.

Normally, I would create a boolean for a single item and just toggle that on/off to check its state and show the new component. Since this is dynamic though, looking for another approach.

Comment: your variable name is r, while you refer to it as showRule_r

Comment: @DavidBulté Correct, rather than having a numeric only variable, I wanted to prepend it with some text.

Comment: yes, but the name is r, you have only renamed the reference. Should be let showRule_r of mapRulesData.data

Comment: also shouldn't the ngFor be on the row iso the tbody?

Comment: Since I am within the `tbody` though where I am inside the ngFor loop, isn't `r` already defined as that?

Comment: I am nesting tables so I am purposely using multiple tbodys in my table, valid markup.

Comment: sorry, i thought everything took place in the table. my mistake

Comment: but is there an edit button per row?

Comment: @DavidBulté There is a button per row, everything inside tbody is to be considered a single unique record.

Comment: but the actual editing takes place in a separate component? You could pass the rowData when clicking the edit button, like so: [click]="doStuff(r)"

Comment: Then in the doStuff(r:any) method, you do sth like: this.selectedData = r . Your "edit component" can be made visible whenever this.selectedData is not undefined

Comment: The editing takes place within the row actually. I have a comma separate list as the value. When I click on "Edit" and I trying to hide the list and replace it with my other component which turns that list into a select dropdown. The ngIf goal here is to hide the list, show the other component.

Comment: you could extract the row in its own component

Comment: or (if possible) wrap that csv value in a "wrapper" object, that also has a flag "showList". Then when clicking edit, you can toggle that value?

Comment: I guess my big question in all this is - Are dynamic variables not allowed in the `ngIf` ? A variable that is generated from a parent `ngFor` for example?

Comment: Sorry now I get what you mean with "rather than having a numeric only variable". But "r" is not numeric here, it IS the name of the variable. No need to prefix it with "showRule"

Comment: Also, there is a variable "r" per row, so there's no need to do anything with the index or so.

Comment: @DavidBulté Thats a little confusing, `r` is the key essentially in the array I am looping over with `ngFor` right? Then, when I call `r.RuleParentID`, it is finding the numeric value in the array of data with that key. `r.RuleParentID` returns unique numbers just fine. I happen to just want the text "showRule_" to come before the number. Resulting in `showRule_1`, `showRule_2`, `showRule_3`, etc.